# NHibernate Transaction Creation is slow

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, fluent-nhibernate

I use Fluent NHibernate 1.3.0.733 which uses NHibernate 3.3.2.4000.
When I use `session.BeginTransaction()`, it takes about 500 ms to create a transaction
and sometimes it goes to more than a second too. Is it there any way to reduce this time?

---

This is in an ASP.NET application with MS SQL Server.
The session is created using a SessionFactory that is created once at Application Start Up.
I implemented session-per-request pattern using ASP.NET modules.
Everything is fine. Session creation does not take time but transaction creation is slow.

Comment: Are you sure the session is being persisted? It takes a while for the factory to initialise - what architecture are you running over? Can you give (a lot) more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple queries and updates, a complete request may be performed in 10-20 ms, including the time to begin and commit transaction, so something is clearly fishy in this case.

With the default configuration, BeginTransaction() is when NHibernate will try to acquire a connection from the underlying ADO.NET. Is connection pooling disabled? Do you have high network latencies to the sql server? Is a distributed transaction coordinator involved?

What happens if you use the same connection string to directly open an ADO.NET connection and transaction?

Comment: Thanks. That's right. Connection pooling was disabled in Web.config. It was on the developer machine and I did not consider till your answer. After enabling, session and transaction creation fall to a few milliseconds.